# Is mozilla firefox ios mode really response like ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, firefox

i am starting to learn react-native and i aim to develop for cross-platform. Since i don't have any mac computer i don't have any ios emulator. I started to discover that mozilla firefox has option for ios mode.

```
Ctrl + Shift + M > (on top of the layout) Edit List.
```

You can choose different OS for mobile phones. Like for Android and IOS. I don't have XCode and i think i can't utilize native things (I don't know details). The question is how far can i expose this for my applications?

What i am trying to do:
In one case, i am planning to acces device camera and take pictures with it and process it with a PyTorch models for predictions. In other just accessing db and showing it to the user like a website. These are some of the examples what i am upto.

Comment: In one case, i am planning to acces device camera and take pictures with it and process it with a PyTorch models for predictions. In other just accessing db and showing it to the user like a website. These are some of the examples what i am upto. @UgurEren you are saying install react-native-web though i installed npm and nodejs i can test on a localhost website. What you are saying is further required to simulate on an emulator?

Comment: I am using expo.